# New to C, trying to better understand char arrays, pointers, reading in files, etc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, logic

Alright, so I am working on linux and emacs for the first time using C, and coming from pretty beginner level java programming in eclipse, my new CS course is really daunting.  SO much stuff has been thrown at me as if I already knew it...

Anyway, the current part of my assignment I am working on involves reading in text from a file (doing that by piping a text file as standard input into my program).  Currently I had three functions, a main function where I read in the file / call other functions, a function that reverses the order of a single word (apple becomes elppa) with *char beg and *char end as parameters, and a function that reverses the order of every word in a line of words, calling the previous function and taking a char *str as a parameter.

I am having trouble reading in the files in my main method in a way that makes it easy to utilize these functions.  Here's a snippet of how I am reading them in currently, but as you can see I haven't figured out a way to store a line of words and send that into my function (I need to reverse line by line, so I can't just add every single char to one long array)

```
enter code here``

char line[8192]
int location = 0;

FILE *in = stdin;
int buff = 0;

while (buff = fgetc(in))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Character is: %d '%c' \n", buff, (char)buff); 
    if (buff == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }

line[location] = (char)buff;
location++;

}
line[location] = '\0';
```

Comment: Use `while (fgets(line sizeof line, in) != NULL) { ...` and then process `line`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a whole line, you can do this:

```
char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
fscanf(in, "%[^\n]", line);
//do whatever you need with the line
fscanf(in, "%[\n]", line);
```

The first fscanf call reads a whole line and store in variable *line*.
But it doesn't skip that line! If you use it again, it will store the very same line.

The second fscanf call is for this: it stores '\n' in variable *line* and skips the line you read previously.

If you want, you can create another buffer to get the '\n' and skip the line:

```
char garbage[2];
fscanf(in, "%[\n]", garbage);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `fscanf(in, "%[^\n]", line); ... fscanf(in, "%[\n]", line);` fails in 3 ways: 1) 1st character is `'\n'`, 2) Input consist of `MAX_LINE_SIZE` characters.   3) Does not handle `EOF`.  Better to use `fgets()`.

Comment: `char garbage[2]; fscanf(in, "%[\n]", garbage);` fail when input is `"\n\n"`.  Using `fscanf(in, "%1[\n]", garbage);` would fix that.

Comment: I have to agree. I have the habbit of using, when needed, this way, but it's better recommended to use fgets() (a good habbit change for me.)

In fact, due to the arguments, fgets, reading from stdin, may be even better then gets to some situations. I already had that need.

Finally: the solution I wrote will get EOF after a "last scan". Basically, it requires a break.